# Selecting timestamp as 00:00:00

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp

let's say I have the below query:

```
SELECT to_char(request_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') date_time
  FROM tableA;
```

The output would be something like:

```
date_time
-------------------------
2015-12-19 11:27:57
```

Now, I want to select the timestamp selected as 00:00:00 no matter what timestamp it actually is. How can i do that? I mean I want the result as below:

```
date_time
-------------------------
2015-12-19 00:00:00
```

Please advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to truncate the date:

```
SELECT to_char(trunc(request_date),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') date_time
```